# "Two Fewer Items" or "Two Items Fewer"?

Tags: grammar, word-order, style-manuals

If I have 10 items in my bag and my friend has 12, which of the following do I say?

> I have **two fewer items** than they do.

or

> I have **two items fewer** than they do.

In [this](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Usage/faq0304.html) page from CMOS, they say:

> There are **two fewer food groups** in the new pyramid.

**Does the order matter?  Do different style guides encourage the use of different orders?**

---

*Note: this is not a question about "fewer" versus "less."*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Either is grammatical, according to the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Huddleston and Pullum 2002).

> The comparative determinatives *more, less, fewer* can occur after the head provided there is a determiner. Thus we have a post-head alternant for *one more day* but not for *more days*: compare *[One day more]/*[Days more] will be needed.*

(Underlining in the original replaced by brackets, p.445)

I haven't yet found a style guide that addresses usage of the two word orders.

Here is a [Wordreference thread about " I ran 2 more miles than her" vs. "I ran 2 miles more than her"](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/2-more-fewer-miles-than-her-vs-2-miles-more-fewer-than-her.3699413/).

Comment: Thank you. This is really helpful.

Comment: The 2 miles example is correct either way, yes, but it's really not the same! The *more* works in either position.

Comment: And *Cambridge…* is actually saying it isn't valid if you have more than one (the asterisk in the quoted example is marking the "days more" as ungrammatical - see the *notational conventions* section at the beginning of the book, which says “The following symbols indicate the status of examples (in the interpretation under 
consideration): 
…
* ungrammatical *This books is mine.
…
”).

Comment: @WillCrawford: It's saying "Days more", without anything before it, is ungrammatical. With a determiner before the noun, "more" can come after whether the noun is singular or plural: "one day more" or "one more day", "two days more" or "two more days", "more days" but not *"days more".

Answer (score -2):

"Two items fewer" is ungrammatical because *fewer* refers to the *number* of items, rather than the *items themselves.*  **Therefore, "two fewer items" is correct.**

So,

> two fewer items

is correct, meaning *the count of my items is two lower than the count of theirs.*

Comment: I'm sorry, but I wasn't clear at all when I asked you to make it an answer.  I just meant the part about the order, not the less vs. fewer debate.  Would you mind removing the less vs. fewer part so I can accept the answer?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I wasn't having a dig, it just seemed humorous :)

Comment: If you meant *all* of it, I can do so but I do feel that part of the explanation does require pointing out the difference..

Comment: I know I'm being annoying, but I do mean all of it.  I just want the answer to the question about the order.  Sorry for the pedantry.  However, thank you for your help!

Comment: No, I got you - I'll trim. It's not about the debate.

Comment: If I've taken too much, or some of the wrong parts out, please go ahead and edit a little if you wish. It's quite hard to separate the bits...

Comment: (mostly because it's 3am here and I'm a little bleary)

Comment: Haha.  I just tried to clean it up.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: I think: thank you - that's a bit clearer, in fact.